# Array extension code results in error "The "this" keyword is disallowed outside of a class body" in TypeScript tslint

Tags: typescript, tslint

I wrote following array extension method code in TypeScript.

```js
interface Array<T> {
  divideInto(n: number): Array<T[]>
}

Array.prototype.divideInto = function<T> (n: number): T[][] {
  const items = this as T[];

  if (n < 1) {
    return []
  }

  const arrList = []
  let index = 0

  while (index < items.length) {
    arrList.push(items.slice(index, index+n))
    index += n
  }
  return arrList
}
```

When I build this code, TSLint says the following error message.

`the "this" keyword is disallowed outside of a class body`

I don't understand what is the problem in my code.

Could anybody give me advices ?

Comment: You shouldn't modify native "classes" like Object, Array, Function and so on. It's a bad practice.

Comment: The problem is not in code, but in tslint rule. You can disable it for this case or generally - depending if you find it useful or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's instead extend the Array class:

```js
class AugmentedArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  divideInto(n: number):T[][] {
    const items = this

    if (n < 1) {
      return []
    }

    const arrList = []
    let index = 0

    while (index < items.length) {
      arrList.push(items.slice(index, index+n))
      index += n
    }

    return arrList
  }
}
```